# Non-blocking gets on Hazelcast ReplicatedMap?

Tags: hazelcast

We are using a ReplicatedMap in a Hazelcast client. Client and server are both version 4.2.1.

The map is quite small (<10 entries, each value less than 100 bytes). The client only reads from the map, which is updated infrequently on the server.

We expected ReplicatedMap.get to be non-blocking, but during a long running performance test, we started getting warnings like the one below from vertx (which monitors for blocked threads). The first error came after 6 hours, so it is not easily reproduced.

Is there any way to do a non-blocking get? Or do we need to add an EntryListener, which maintains a ConcurrentHashmap?

Clarification: The real issue here is not blocking vertx (which can be solved by moving the call to a Vertx worker verticle), but rather avoiding delaying the lookup. The business requirement is that we process messages in 50 ms or less, so even if we moved the call to a worker, we would be unable to fulfill that.

```
[vertx-blocked-thread-checker] WARN  io.vertx.core.impl.BlockedThreadChecker - Thread Thread[vert.x-eventloop-thread-0,5,main] has been blocked for 12777 ms, time limit is 2000 ms
io.vertx.core.VertxException: Thread blocked
    at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:323) ~[?:?]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.manageParking(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:693) ~[hazelcast-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.AbstractInvocationFuture.get(AbstractInvocationFuture.java:615) ~[hazelcast-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.ClientProxy.invokeOnPartition(ClientProxy.java:188) ~[hazelcast-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.spi.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:182) ~[hazelcast-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at com.hazelcast.client.impl.proxy.ClientReplicatedMapProxy.get(ClientReplicatedMapProxy.java:214) ~[hazelcast-4.2.1.jar!/:4.2.1]
    at my.package.StateGetter.getState(StateGetter.java:44) ~[classes!/:1.5.189]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReplicatedMap` entries are replicated on all members of the cluster. A client still needs to perform a remote call to a member to fetch the entry. For your requirements, I think the best way to achieve predictable latency is to setup a [near cache](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/performance/near-cache) on your client. This way entries will be cached locally on the client and only updated whenever necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Golden rule of vertx is not to block the event loop in the app and the blocking tolerance is very low (2 sec). However, since we often need to execute blocking operations vertx offers two solutions. The one that I prefer to use are Worker verticles (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_verticles under the Worker verticles section). You start them with the following code:

```
DeploymentOptions options = new DeploymentOptions().setWorker(true);
vertx.deployVerticle("com.verticles.HazelcastVerticle", options);
```

This type of verticle is designed for blocking operations and has a much higher tolerance before warnings start (60 sec by default). If you expect the operation to be longer than that you will probably need a separate thread or a different approach, but from your question I assume that is not the case so I won't go in that direction.

Other approach is to use `vertx.executeBlocking`. Details about that you can find here: https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-run-blocking-code-in-vertx.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is not so much the vertx warning as the actual blocking. The business requirement is to process requests fast (less then 50 ms). Moving the get() call to a worker verticle will prevent blocking vertx, but it will still be too slow to meet the business requirement. So the question is, how do we prevent this call from being blocking?

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted the problem and assumed you have an issue with vertx instead of Hazelcast. Unfortunately, with that I don't have enough knowledge to give you any meaningful advice, best of luck!